# black screen after storyboard delete

Tags: ios, xcode

I deleted story board and maininterface and from info plist  now black screen appears with this code below

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UIWindow * window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds] ];
    UIViewController *UVC=[[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UVC.view.bounds=[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds] ;
    UVC.title=@"AAA";
    UVC.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    window.rootViewController = UVC;
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    application.delegate.window=window;
    return YES;
}
```

its ios 13 issue.

Comment: Go to your target settings. Choose `General` tab and check if you delete storyboard name from `Main Interface` deployment info.

Comment: i already did it

Comment: if project created recently and it for iOS 13 try to use SceneDelegate not AppDelegate
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate